# How to add a text to be like attached to a gameobject relative to the gameobject rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this model and the model is rotated on the x by -90 so the model is a bit pointing to the ground on the left side :

[image: sci fi spaceship]

and now i want to write some text on it's side on the surface.
the easiest way is just to add a simple empty gameobject as child of the ship and to add to the child a Text Mesh component :

[image: spaceship with text]

but now i have to play a lot with the text object rotation and position to find the exact settings that it will be like painted/attached/curved on the ship surface and to be in the same rotation pointing a bit down to the ground to the left like the ship.

and even if playing with it so much time it will never be 100% accurate.

is there any way to attach/pint/curved the text with the same rotation of the ship easier ?

Comment: maybe this [Surface Align Tool](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/surface-align-tool-223640) plugin might be useful. It is free to use.

Comment: Or decals.. unity decals should work too